# How do I duplicate a single wpmu site?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wpml, duplicates

I'm looking for a method to copy a single wpmu site, pages, and content easily. I have not found any plugins that allow me to do this. My goal is to essentially have a template of pages and content that I can replicate.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of [BackupBuddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) you can actually do exactly that!